# How to merge two DataTables by primary key and foreign key (right join)?

Tags: c#, .net, merge, datatable, dataset

Is there a way, to merge two dataTables table1 and table2 by different keys?

Want to do `dataTable.Merge` by `t1 PK_id` and `t2 ParentId`. Is this possible if `ParentId` is not a `PK`?

***table1***

```
PK_id   Name
--------------
  1     test1
  2     test2
  3     test3
```

***table2***

```
PK_id2  ShortName  ParentId
---------------------------
   1       a           1
   2       b           1
   3       c           2
```

***Result is a right join***

```
PK_id   Name   PK_id2  ShortName  ParentId
------------------------------------------------
   1    test1     1        a          1
   1    test1     2        b          1
   2    test2     3        c          2
   3    test3    null     null      null
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you expect to get as a result?

Comment: Could please somebody help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to do this merge in C# or using SQL?

Comment: Sorry. I´m trying to do it in C# w/wo linq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using linq will probably be your best bet. There will be some extra things you'll have to add to your code but this example does a really nice job of explaining it.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326080/en-us